# Get and save ANY file selected with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, io, android-fileprovider

I need to accomplish these steps:

1. Let the user select a file ( any kind of file )
2. Get a permanent reference to access the file later or copy to my internal storage.

The first one is really a easy. I don't have any problems in fetch the file using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT. I also can get the MimeType of the file. But I can't copy.

I tried to copy using a **FileInputStream**, but apparently I don't have the permission to it. I really hope that somebody can help me.

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

**Intent Call**

```
    Intent intent   = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    if ( intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FILE_GET);
    }
```

**Failed attempt to copy the file**

```
 FileInputStream in = (FileInputStream) getContentResolver().openInputStream( data.getData());
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( "copy.jpg ");
 FileChannel inChannel   = in.getChannel();
 FileChannel outChannel  = out.getChannel();
 inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
 in.close();
 out.close();
```

Error: `android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)`

Comment: 'FileInputStream in = (FileInputStream) getContentResolver().openInputStream( data.getData());' That looks wrong. I'm supprised you ĉome away with it. Better: InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream( data.getData());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to create the output stream file in the root directory, `/copy.jpg`, which is read-only.

Use one of the [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) methods, such as `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, or one of the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) methods such as `getFilesDir()`, to build a path to a directory you have write access to.

For example:

```
File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "copy.jpg");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```

This [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) describes the different options for storing files in internal or external storage.

Comment: So obvious! Thanks a lot. Worked line a charm.